# Usage of Aggregate function in R for slices within for loop

Tags: r

I'm comparing the created date value at each row with the minimum removed date value for that user until row-1 index at which the loop currently stands

I tried to create a function which would be passed with `1:i-1` range of data and the current loop's user id.

```
minif<- function(data,user){
  data<-as.data.frame(data)
  user<-as.numeric(unlist(user))
  aggregate(data$removed_at,list(user=data$user_id),min)
}

for(i in 2:nrow(mydf1)){
  if (mydf1$created_at[i]<=minif(mydf1[1:i-1,],as.numeric(mydf1$user_id[i]))){
    mydf1$test[i]=1
  }
  else
    mydf1$test[i]=0
}
```

The expected output should have been 1 for the rows that meet the criteria, however it gives me an error:

> (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Comment: Pleasse show a small reproducible example

Comment: Please post input data and desired results. Your process is not too clear.

Answer (score 0):

An option would be

```
library(dplyr)  
mydf %>%
      group_by(user_id) %>%
      mutate(test = as.integer(created_at <=  cummin(lag(removed_at, 
                  default = first(removed_at)))))
```